# Intersection of Height One Primary Ideals is Principal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $R$ be a UFD having height one primary ideals $\mathfrak q_1,...,\mathfrak q_r$. My purpose is to show that their intersection is principal.

I do know that in a UFD each prime ideal of height one is principal.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A height one primary ideal in a UFD is principal and generated by a power of a prime.

Let $\mathfrak q$ be a $\mathfrak p$-primary ideal of height one. Then $\mathfrak p=(p)$ with $p\in R$ a prime element. We have $\mathfrak q\subseteq (p)$. Suppose $\mathfrak q\subseteq (p^n)$, and $\mathfrak q\nsubseteq(p^{n+1})$. Since $\sqrt{\mathfrak q}=(p)$, there is $k\ge 1$ such that $p^k\in\mathfrak q$. Then $k=n$, so $(p^n)\subseteq\mathfrak q$.

Comment: What happens if $q \subset \cap_{n \geq 0}(p^{n}) ?$ I mean why it cannot happen ?

Comment: @user371231 In a UFD which elements are divisible by $p^n$, for every $n\ge 1$?

Comment: Ok, thank you. It is elementary but seems to me very useful.